# Bot framework Form Flow Pattern Matching and Regex

Tags: c#, regex, botframework, formflow

I'm am trying to pattern make a form attribute to ***accept only Text and numbers with no White space and no Special characters.*** I Tried several Regex expressions, but it doesn't go, Please help. Here is my code for the Form flow attribute

```
[Pattern(@"^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$")]
```

Comment: Then why use `,\s-` and `\.` in the pattern? How do you define *Text* and *numbers*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently used

```
^[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df]+[a-zA-Z\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6\u00dc\u00fc\u00df0-9_]*$
```

It includes the german Umlaute (äöüÄÖÜ) as well as the Eszett (ß) i think. You can remove all those \uXXXX characters